# EasyAdmin, how can I add custom column to grid?

Tags: php, symfony, crud, easyadmin

I want to add a column not in my entity and require some custom query/subquery. For eg. I have an entity with users assigned to it, and I want a column that will show the user count, but only active users, or only users created after some date. I was trying to add a field to the query builder but then I'm getting an error related to '"id as an array". Is this even possible using Easyadmin?

For test I was trying to add any field to query builder

```php
public function createIndexQueryBuilder(SearchDto $searchDto, EntityDto $entityDto, FieldCollection $fields, FilterCollection $filters): QueryBuilder
{
[...]
    $queryBuilder->addSelect('1 AS userCount');
    return $queryBuilder;
}
```

but then i'm gettin error
`Cannot read property "id" from an array. Maybe you intended to write the property path as "[id]" instead.`
I dumped paginator from AbstractCrudController::index and saw that results now have little diffrent structure

```
  -results: ArrayIterator {#900 ▼
    -storage: array:10 [▼
      0 => array:2 [▼
        0 => App\Entity\Company {#916 ▶}
        "userCount" => 1
      ]
      1 => array:2 [▼
        0 => App\Entity\Company {#814 ▶}
        "userCount" => 1
      ]
```

Normaly you only have array of entities not array of array with entity and custom value.

Answer (score 1):

I've found some kind of solution to this problem. It's not perfect, because you will need to query the database per each row. Also, it feels kinda hacky.

You can add columns that don't exist in your model and this is fine. Method `setValue` cannot take callable but `foramtValue` can, so something like this works quite well

```php
   yield TextField::new('userCount')
            ->setValue('0')
            ->formatValue(function ($value, $entity) {
                return $this->userRepository->count(['company' => $entity->getId()]);
            })
            ->onlyOnIndex();
```

You need to set the value to some default value for `formatValue` to work.